# How to share between all buttons a width of the widest button within a StackPanel?

Tags: wpf, xaml

For instance, I have this markup:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="PreviousPage"
                Content="Previous" />
        <Button x:Name="Info"
                Content="Information" />
        <Button x:Name="InetTicket"
                Content="Internet ticket" />
        <Button x:Name="FindStation"
                Content="Find station" />
        <Button x:Name="NextPage"
                Content="Next" />        
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

How to determine the widest button and share it's size with the other buttons. So the buttons should be of the same width at the end. How to accomplish such a task using xaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `Grid` with `IsSharedSizeScope`, instead of `StackPanel`, like below:

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="buttons"/>
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="buttons"/>
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="buttons"/>
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="buttons"/>
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="buttons"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Button x:Name="PreviousPage" Content="Previous" Grid.Column="0"/>
   <Button x:Name="Info" Content="Information" Grid.Column="1"/>
   <Button x:Name="InetTicket" Content="Internet ticket" Grid.Column="2"/>
   <Button x:Name="FindStation" Content="Find station" Grid.Column="3"/>
   <Button x:Name="NextPage" Content="Next" Grid.Column="4"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a uniform grid which will make sure all the buttons are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UniformGrid`:

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1">
    <Button x:Name="PreviousPage"
            Content="Previous" />
    <Button x:Name="Info"
            Content="Information" />
    <Button x:Name="InetTicket"
            Content="Internet ticket" />
    <Button x:Name="FindStation"
            Content="Find station" />
    <Button x:Name="NextPage"
            Content="Next" />        
</UniformGrid>
```